# cannot connect to container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker 1.12 and docker-compose 1.12, on OSX.

I created a docker-compose.yml file which runs two containers:

- the first, named spark, builds and runs a sparkjava application
- the second, named behave, runs some functional tests on the API exposed by the first container.

  ```
  version: "2"

  services:

  behave:
      build:
          context: ./src/test
      container_name: "behave"
      links:
        - spark
      depends_on:
        - spark
      entrypoint: ./runtests.sh spark:9000

  spark:
      build:
          context: ./
      container_name: "spark"
      ports:
        - "9000:9000"
  ```

As [recommended by Docker Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), I use a simple shell script to test if the spark server is ready. This script is name runtest.sh, and runs into the container named "behave". It is launched by docker-compose (see above):

````
#!/bin/bash

# This scripts waits for the API server to be ready before running functional tests with Behave
# the parameter should be the hostname for the spark server
set -e

host="$1"
echo "runtests host is $host"

until curl -L "http://$host"; do
  >&2 echo "Spark server is not ready - sleeping"
  sleep 5
done

>&2 echo "Spark server is up - starting tests"
behave
```
````

The DNS resolution does not seem to work. curl makes a request to spark.com instead of a request to my container named "spark".

**UPDATE:**

By setting an alias for my link (`links: -spark:myserver`), I've seen the DNS resolution is not done by Docker: I received an error message from a corporate network equipment (I'm running this from behind a corporate proxy, with Docker for Mac). Here is an extract of the output:

```
Recreating spark
Recreating behave
Attaching to spark, behave
behave    | runtests host is myserver:9000
behave    |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
behave    |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   672  100   672    0     0    348      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   348
behave    | <HTML><HEAD>
behave    | <TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
behave    | </HEAD>
behave    | <BODY>
behave    | ...
behave    | <big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>
behave    | Your requested host "myserver" could not be resolved by DNS.
behave    | ...
behave    | </BODY></HTML>
behave    | Spark server is up - starting tests
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you need the `links` entry. *Links allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is reachable from another service.*

Comment: It's not what I read here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/links. I tried however, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it no longer applies to your edited question. Consider including logs of your script output, and other commands to test DNS (e.g. ping) to isolate the problem to either DNS or curl.

Comment: And @R0MANARMY is correct in saying you don't need `links`, it's replaced with the DNS integration.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clearer at first I was running the script in the second container. As I said, removing "links" does not solve the problem, have you another idea?

Comment: I added an update to my question, I have some more info.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I added an environment variable `no_proxy` for the name of the container I wanted to join.

In the dockerfile for the container behave, I have:

```
ENV http_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080
ENV https_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080
ENV no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost,spark
```